# Meaning of "if you're on one like me in mind"?

Tags: phrases, lyrics

It's from Bruno Mars's song "Finesse", somehow I don't get it. Context:

Fellas, grab your ladies if your lady fine

Tell her she the one, she the one for life

Ladies, grab your fellas and let's do this right

If you're on one like me in mind

Answer (score 1):

The previous two lines

> Fellas, grab your ladies if your lady fine
>
> Tell her she the one, she the one for life

are clear advice for men. The next two lines

> Ladies, grab your fellas and let's do this right
>
> If you're on one like me in mind

are complementary to the first pair. Adding some punctuation makes the meaning clear:

> Ladies, grab your fellas and let's do this right
>
> If you're on one *(a man)*, like me, in *(your)* mind.

But it has a different cast: the singer is also referring to *him* and is saying

> If a lady has **me** in mind she should grab me.

Comment: Not exactly clear. Can you elaborate?